# What is this piece of land?

Tags: game-of-thrones

There is this new [3D video](http://www.edna.cz/game-of-thrones/videa/podivejte-se-na-360-uvodni-znelku-game-of-thrones/) (also [here on GoT Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/GameOfThrones/videos/10153647535247734/)) from the opening credits of GoT. When I point the camera to the far south, I can see a strange piece of land:

[image]

I am quite confused: is it Ulthos or Sothoryos? If yes, why is it covered by snow and ice? Has this island/continent ever been mentioned on the official map or in books?

Comment: Are you sure this is in the far south?

Comment: @randal'thor Well, I am not sure... I went to the south so long that I might have appeared in the north :-)... However, I can really see this island south-east of the Slavers Bay and south of Quarth...

Comment: Maybe it's a new continent that hasn't been described so far? You might like to check out [this awesome resource](http://quartermaester.info/), which doesn't show anything cold and icy southeast of Slaver's Bay.

Comment: @randal'thor According to [this map](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/The_Known_World?file=The_known_world_HBO.jpg) there is no island in this area but Sothoryos, which should be much larger though... I think it must be some obscure effect of the 3D framework, otherwise it makes no sense.

Comment: There's some slanted writing which looks like a label up towards the top left of the image in your question. If we could read that, it might give us the answer ...

Comment: @randal'thor I tried, but I can't read it. Try the video by yourself, the link is in my post above. It is quite funny, btw :-)

Comment: I did look at the video, but every time I tried to use the 3D visuals, it just went black and I couldn't see anything.

Comment: The website is in (Romanian?). Is the writing in the video translated to the same? Cus ive got as close as I can to the label. Two words (3 letters and 6, possibly seven), but can't make out what it says. I'm not familiar enuff with it to be sure, but look at Ulthos here https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjzuov59pDMAhXHxxQKHcJYDRYQjRwIBw&url=http%3A%2F%2Ficeandfire.wikia.com%2Fwiki%2FFile%3AIce_and_Fire_World_Map.png&psig=AFQjCNGMT5Gpz6iuKnf4fyMCa_xC3LkOiA&ust=1460819516271538 . The left side looks like top left of the image OP posted

Comment: @MacCooper The website is Czech, but the video is in English. It is from the [GoT official Facebook page](https://www.google.cz/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjRs83LgZHMAhWjDZoKHZ-TC1cQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FGameOfThrones%2Fvideos%2F10153647535247734%2F&usg=AFQjCNFdrQvyE5QOBHT6SyVZIME-Lv8jSQ&sig2=12rcuDtiYTFv1ERlUev4rA). Looks like Ulthos, I agree, but it should be farther in the east, I suppose.

Comment: Can you tell us which episode this intro is from? (They tend to change from episode to episode).

Comment: @Mooz It is not from an episode. It is a special 3D 360° video they posted on the official Facebook page as a trailer for the upcoming season. See my link in the post.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]

Quoting OP vojta from the conversation bellow:
"According to [GoT Wiki](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Asshai), there should be the Shadow Lands on the eastern shores of the Jade Sea with the only known location - the city of Asshai. I think Asshai could be at the end of the peninsula right under your huge red question mark."

Reason the island is shown white like it would be covered in snow/ice is "[ghost grass](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Ghost_grass)"
Quote from Got Wiki: "Ghost Grass, with stalks as pale as milk that glow in the night."

Comment: Excellent work! You managed to track the whole journey from the known lands to The Mysterious Island! And I see a possible answer now: The Mysterious Island could be Ibben north of Essos, projected by the 3D visual both to the southern and nothern part of the map (in 360 there must be a point where the north meets the south). The only problem is "The Narrow (Sea?)" label, Ibben is really far from it...

Comment: Another hypothesis: number 4 is out of your map, actually. And so is number 5. Number 4 could be at the top of the peninsula in the northeast part of Essos, where it leaves your map. The Mysterious Island would be some area not described by the official map then. "The Narrow" label is a problem again.

Comment: It's not Ibben. I decided to give 3D video another look and found something i missed. The mysterious island is behind The Jade Sea (Nr. 10) I update picture.

Comment: About "The Narrow", it's marked with Number 5 and it's the same thing visible in your screenshot, people couldn't read it, so i made a better one in which you can. Considering it all, I don't think it's meant "The Narrow Sea", but just "The Narrow". That makes more sense, doesn't it? Well.. It could be a new territory that is still not revealed either in books and tv series.

Comment: According to [GoT Wiki](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Asshai), there should be the Shadow Lands on the eastern shores of the Jade Sea with the only known location - the city of Asshai. I think Asshai could be at the end of the peninsula right under your huge red question mark.

Comment: See [this map of Asshai](https://qph.is.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-4154182b6214cb00cc53dc2a0411d4f6?convert_to_webp=true), although it is probably made by fans, so it is rather irrelevant.

Comment: That could be it, i but just wonder, why would it be covered in ice/snow..

Comment: What about the "ghost grass"?

Comment: Hmm, you might be right. Quote from got wiki "Ghost Grass, with stalks as pale as milk that glow in the night."

Comment: Done. Will this do?

Answer (score 6):

It is **[The Grey Waste](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Grey_Waste)**:

> The Grey Waste appears to be an expansive, cold desert in far eastern Essos.

There is not much information about this part of the world and GRRM has famously and intentionally left these details blank.

Note, in the official [The Lands of Ice and Fire](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/The_Lands_of_Ice_and_Fire) maps, the Grey Waste is not disconnected from Essos, rather it is the easternmost section of Essos. The image you've linked could be a derived artist's depiction of the area.

You can see that there is nothing further east of The Grey Waste [here](http://www.fantasticmaps.com/2013/03/official-world-map-of-a-song-of-ice-and-fire/):
[image: Full map of the World of Ice and Fire]

<sup>[image src: http://i2.wp.com/www.fantasticmaps.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/World_Of_Ice_And_Fire.jpg]</sup>